# Setting String Values of a Pandas Column with Indices

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to generate a new column in my dataframe where a string is assigned for different index values. I'm not exactly skilled enough to do it with a loop, so I tried subsetting and indexing to see if I could make my life easier.

```
df['event_type'] = []

A = df[df['flags'].isin(['A'])].index
B= df[df['flags'].isin(['B'])].index
C = df[df['flags'].isin(['B'])].index


df.loc[A, 'event_type'] = 'Condition One'
df.loc[B, 'event_type'] = 'Condition Two'
df.loc[C, 'event_type'] = 'Condition Three'
```

I've gotten the length of values does not match length of index and Index.name must be a hashable type errors several times now. I just want to assign these strings to these indices in the new columns, all the other values in the column can be Nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map),

```
df['event_type'] = df.flags.fillna('').map(
    {"A": "Condition One", "B": "Condition Two", "C": "Condition Three"}
)
```